# ignore 404 Azure WebSites DetailedError logging

Tags: logging, azure-web-app-service

I got many 404 HttpStatus logging in my Azure WebSites filesystem logging, checked by FTP `LogFiles/DetailedErrors/ErrorPage0000##.htm` files.

They are not meaningful to me as I do to respond 404 in some controllers. How to ignore them to be recorded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use elmah and filter out errors you dont want - http://sweetsciencecoding.com/filtering-errors-in-elmah/